# How can I exclude certain salaries and then order by?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I am  working with an SQL database with several tables, each with approximately 170,000 records. The data was all originally in separate XLSX files that I saved as CSV and then imported into SQLite.

One of the columns is "TotSalary". I am trying to do 2 things with this column. A lot of the entries seem defunct, as "TotSalary" is "$0.00". I would like to exclude entries with a salary of 0.

I have tried:

```
WHERE (other conditions here)
   AND (other conditions here)
   AND 'TotSalary' IS NOT '$0.00'
```

as well as

```
WHERE (other conditions here)
   AND (other conditions here)
   AND 'TotSalary' != '$0.00'
```

Neither of these are working. If I say 'TotSalary' = '$0.00', the query returns no records, so somehow I am not targeting the value properly. I looked at the operators for SQLite and both != and NOT are proper operators. Do I need to adjust any syntax?

Finally, I would like to be able to ORDER BY 'TotSalary' as well. The problem is that the query is using lexicographic ordering. "$100,000" is a lower salary than "$20,000" when ordered.

[image]

One site suggested changing the data type for the column (they are all TEXT by default). I tried changing the type to NUMERIC, and then INTEGER, neither of which made any difference.

I also tried `ORDER BY cast('TotSalary' as int) DESC` but this did not work either.

Comment: Does your salary column have the $ in it?  If so you can not cast it as int with the $ in it.  (and if it does this is not a good idea to include this in a coulumn that should be a decimal)

Comment: Fix your import, and import the salaries as _numbers_, not as text.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the $ when casting? Could I modify column type now instead of reimporting? Also, it did not work either when the data type was "Numeric". Is the $ also preventing the != from working?

Comment: try like this: select '3.33' + 0.0;

Comment: @SergiuCostas If I do select ... TotSalary+0.0 instead of select .... TotSalary then all the entries in the column are '0.0'

Comment: in your query, you would need twice select this parameter: one for display as currency, and secondly for transformation to number... Something like: Select TotSalary, TotSalary AS SpecialNumber ... ORDER BY SpecialNumber... I will come back with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work (**financial** being the table name) :-

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM financial 
WHERE CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL) > 0.00 
ORDER BY CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL) DESC
```

This will remove the commas and dollar sign using the `replace` function.
It then `CAST`'s the resultant number to a `REAL` allowing it to be compared against 0.00, thus allowing rows with 0 to be excluded.

ORDER uses the same replace and cast to correctly order.

You could simplifiy the above, but at the cost of an additional column by using :-

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL) AS cnv 
FROM financial WHERE cnv > 0.00 
ORDER BY cnv DESC
```

An alternative approach could be to convert the rows in the database, thus negating the need to convert the column e.g. you could use:-

```
UPDATE financial 
    SET TotSalary = CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL);
```

- Note an assumption has been made that a salary will never be negative.

> I tried changing the type to NUMERIC, and then INTEGER, neither of
>   which made any difference.

Column type has a very limited impact, in short any type of value can be saved in any type of column. The only limitation/restriction being that an alias of the **rowid** column (column type is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`) can only store an integer.
You may wish to have a look at [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: base on your answer: 
SELECT *,  CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS SPECIAL) FROM table
WHERE SPECIAL > 0 AND OTHERS ORDER BY SPECIAL